# Finding coefficients of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

My question is related to another question that I asked before which is about solving a recursive ODE.

I received some complicated answers but think there might be a simpler way and part of this approach is to identify the general pattern of coefficients in a series.

For example, we have
\begin{align*}
&n=1\quad 1 \\
&n=2\quad 2+x\\
&n=3\quad 6+4x+x^2\\
&n=4\quad 24+18x+6x^2+x^3\\
&n=5\quad 120+96x+36x^2+8x^3+x^4
\end{align*}

So I thought for every $n$, we write the series as
$$\sum_{i=1}^nc_{in}x^{i-1}$$
and then find what $c_{in}$s are.

We can say $c_{1n}=n!$, $c_{nn}=1$.

I thought I can write the rest of coefficients recursively but I'm having some problems there.
Could someone give me a hint please?

Comment: Looks like what you want is at https://oeis.org/A324224 and https://oeis.org/A121757

Comment: Had a look at those links, Vultra?

Comment: Yes, I studied them. The coefficients were exactly like in my question but I couldn't get a recursive formula to generate them.

Comment: Don't those links give a closed form for the coefficients? Isn't that better than a recurrence?

Comment: I was so caught up in the idea of a recursion that I didn't even think about that! Thank you for pointing this out. I look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is

$$c_{i,n}=(n-i)c_{i,n-1}+c_{i-1,n-1}$$

where $i$ starts at $0$.

Comment: Thank you. I see the general idea but when I tried to generate some of the coefficients, I don't get the same as in the example. So say for $n=1$, $c_{11}=c_{00}=1$ but then for $n=2$, $c_{12}=c_{11}+c_{01}$. Did I get it wrong?

Comment: It's $n-i$ not $n-1$.

Comment: I don't see where to use that!

Comment: $96=(5-1)\times18+24, 8=(5-3)1+6$